# Compare column summing value with another column - Criteria grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I tried to do similar to low but not right

```
    def results = Transportadora.createCriteria().list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset ?: 0) {
        or {
            lt('validadeRange', reminderDate)
            gtProperty('atualRange + 1000','fimRange')
        }
        ilike('tipo','Correios') 
        if (params['filter']) {
            or {
                ilike("firstName", "%${params.filter}%")
                ilike("lastName", "%${params.filter}%")
            }
        }
        if (params.order) {
            order(params.sort, params.order)
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do and get the value of the 'atualRange' (current Range) column add up to 1000 and compare if it is larger than the 'fimRange' (Range end).

```
gtProperty('atualRange + 1000','fimRange')
```

But I have another problem in my Domain the 'atualRange' is roturn as String

```
class Transportadora{

    String nome
    String codigo
    String tipo
    String via
    Float limPesoVolume //limite de peso por volume
    Float limDimVolume  //limite de dimensões por volume
    Float altLim //Altura limite
    Float largLim //Largura limite
    Float profLim //Profundidade limite

    //static hasMany = [tiposEmbalagem: TipoEmbalagem]

    static constraints = {
        codigo(blank: false, unique: "tenantId")
        nome(blank: false)
        tipo(nullable:true, inList:["Cliente", "Motoboy", "Correios", "Transportadora"])
        via(nullable:true, inList:["Rodoviária", "Aérea"], display:true)
        tenantId(nullable: false, display: false)
        idServicoCorreio(nullable:true)
        codigoServico(nullable:true)
        altLim(nullable:true)
        largLim(nullable:true)
        profLim(nullable:true)
        inicioRange(nullable:true)
        atualRange(nullable:true)
        fimRange(nullable:true)
        validadeRange(nullable:true)
        cabecalhoEtiqueta(nullable:true)
    }

    public String toString() {
        nome
    }

    //uso para correios
    Long idServicoCorreio

    //uso para correios
    String codigoServico

    //para uso do range dos correios
    String cabecalhoEtiqueta

    String inicioRange

    String fimRange

    String atualRange

    Date validadeRange
}
```

Does anyone know how to help me do this? Do I have to stake a variable in my class to do the manipulation of values and only then call them on the Criteria list?

Answer (score 0):

`sqlRestriction` should do what you want:

```
def results = Transportadora.createCriteria().list() {
    or {
       lt('validadeRange', reminderDate)
       sqlRestriction 'atualRange + 1000 > fimRange'
    }
}
```

see http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#criteria